# jQuery on() syntax

Tags: jquery, syntax

I have a newbie syntax question, here is my code:

```
$('.selector').on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    // ...
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    // ...
  }
});
```

Now what if I wanted to bind the mouseenter and touchstart events to the same function? I know I can do this:

```
$('.selector').on('mouseenter touchstart', function(){
  // ...
});
```

But I like the look of my first example. (Am I right in thinking that it is only the syntaxt that differs in my examples?) Also does anyone know where I can look up these kind of things? The jQuery API only ever show one way writing things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the two events bind to the same function, then *bind them to the same function!*

If you create two anonymous functions with identical bodies, you'll be using more memory than you need to because you will have actually created two separate functions.

In that sense, your two examples are *not* semantically identically.

Alternatively, declare the callback function *once* outside (i.e. not as an anonymous function) and use the first syntax:

```
var cb = function(ev) { ... }

$(el).on({
    mouseenter: cb,
    touchstart: cb
});
```

Comment: The OP is aware of this, and is asking if there's a way to bind to the same function using the first syntax.

Comment: Just refreshed, I see it now.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way

```
 $('.selector').on({
       mouseenter : move,
       touchstart : move
   });

    function move(){

    }
```

If you want to define different functionalities to the two events go by this approach.

If the functionality is the same for both then your code should work..

Comment: or just `mouseenter: move` - no need for the extra layer of `function()` blocks.